# Minimize all open windows?

Tags: winapi

I need to perform the same task as WindowsKey + M through code, ie. minimize all open windows. This must be done through the Win32 API, not .Net.

I tried the following in FreeBasic, but nothing happens:

```
Dim hWndConsole As HWND
'Shell_TrayWnd = class name of taskbar
Dim WindowName as String = "Shell_TrayWnd"

hWndConsole = FindWindow(0, strptr(WindowName))
ShowWindow(hWndConsole, SW_MINIMIZE) 'outta my sight
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Here's the working solution:

```
#include "Windows.bi"

Dim hWndConsole As HWND
'Shell_TrayWnd = class name of taskbar
Dim WindowName as String = "Shell_TrayWnd"
Dim res as LRESULT
CONST minall = 419

hWndConsole = FindWindow( "Shell_TrayWnd",null)

res = postMessage(hWndConsole, WM_COMMAND,  minall, null )
```

Comment: You know, I really wouldn't appreciate this feature if it were running on my computer. And, while I don't use Windows, I can't imagine (and would hope) that this isn't possible.

Comment: No problem, as it's for my very own personal use ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a hack to me, but the following does seem to accomplish what you are looking for (in C):

```
HANDLE hwnd = FindWindow( "Shell_TrayWnd", NULL );
LRESULT res = SendMessage( hwnd, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)419, 0 );
```

Comment: 419 is also known as `MIN_ALL`. There is also `MIN_ALL_UNDO` (416).

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Just out of curiosity, do you know what header file that is in?  I do see references to that via Google searches, but I cannot seem to find it in any Microsoft header file on my PC.

Comment: `MIN_ALL` and `MIN_ALL_UNDO` are not defined in any header file, and they are not documented by Microsoft, since people are not supposed to be manipulating the `Shell_TrayWnd` window directly. But they are known constants that can be found online in various discussions, including several on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the handle of a window, you can make it minimize with the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message. E.g.:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
```

So all you would need to do is enumerate the top-level windows (with the `EnumWindows` command) and send that command to the windows you want to minimize (which wouldn't be all top-level windows - probably only visible, overlapped windows without the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style should be minimized like this).

Answer (score 0):

Putting this out as an option, not a recommendation - simulating the keyboard events for `Win-M`:

```
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event('M', 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about keybd_event()